# Link Spring JPA and WAMP

Tags: java, spring, jpa, wamp

I must link a Spring project using JPA and a localhost database. I use WAMP for this. But, I can't find any solution to solve my probleme. Somebody has a tutorial or any explication to link everything ?

Cordially,

Comment: You do know that WAMP means windows/apache/mysql/php? If so, what have you installed next to this software stack?

Comment: Yes, I know what WAMP means. I installed mysql-connector-java to try to link all these tools.